# Magento 1.7 cannot reindex product flat data

Tags: magento-1.7, reindex

### Magento 1.7 cannot reindex product flat data... I get the following error when trying to reindex my database.

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot          add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`d014505f`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-1f6c_39a11d'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`e)' in /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Stack trace:#0 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement-    >execute(Array)
#1 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(340): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2569): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /www/htdocs/w00f5624/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magento programatically re index

```
ID      Code

1       catalog_product_attribute

2       catalog_product_price

3       catalog_url

4       catalog_product_flat

5       catalog_category_flat

6       catalog_category_product

7       catalogsearch_stock

8       cataloginventory_stock

9       tag_summary
```

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems Magento did not clean the table when you have deleted some informations; so you need to clean it manually, using this SQL query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ´catalog_product_flat_1´;
```

Then, run reindex process.

It's okay to empty that table; since Magento uses EAV tables to rebiuld (reindex) it again.

Comment: No, that didn't do it.. Here is the methiod that worked perfectly..

(http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/magento-1-7-cannot-reindex-product-flat-data/1544?noredirect=1#1544)

Comment: It worked for me, exactly the same problem in mage 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue today. To fix this, just locate the corrupted products by running

```
SELECT cpf.entity_id FROM catalog_product_flat_1 AS cpf LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cpf.entity_id = cpe.entity_id WHERE ISNULL(cpe.entity_id);
```

You'll get a result like

```
+-----------+
| entity_id |
+-----------+
|     14029 |
|     14111 |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now you can just delete these products by running

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_1 where entity_id IN (14029,14111);
```

**Note: You might need to change the "catalog_product_flat_1" table - the error message tells you which table contains the corrupted products.**

Answer (score 0):

I've got almost the same error:
(something like that) SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'databasename.#sql-4ebf-e07' (errno: 121)

Then I've researched that I have the same foreign key 'FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID'

Even if I truncate a table like this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

didn't solve my problem.

Even if I drop all tables in DB, I couldn't drop only 3 of them at all:
catalog_product_entity, and couple eav_ tables (I don't remember)

Only one way had helped me:

1. Make backup of current DB (do this before any changes, even if you've got message to reindex)
2. Drop DB (not all tables, but directly DB)
3. Create DB (check that you still have privileges)
4. Restore DB from backup and check Admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_2;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Worked for me.

Afterwards I could reindex from CLI.